# Pause macro and let user select color

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to make this macro stop when it opens the format cells fill dialogue so I can choose the color and have the script continue when OK is selected.

```
Sub StripesOdd()

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=MOD(ROW(),2)=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Application.Goto Reference:="StripesOdd"
End Sub
```

Comment: it's possible to ask for an input. think of a way you would select the color? maybe using a userform with an activeX component that has a range of colors?

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/547126-excel-colors-dialog-visual-basic-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Before you continue down this path too far - VBA is an automation tool. If i was you, I'd spend more time on setting the colors based on data (ie if field equals "x" then color blue) rather than allowing the user do it randomly. It is not automation if manual intervention is required.

You need to insert a user input into the code which requires the user to make a selection before the codes continues.

Found this on http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Colors.aspx
It does requires the modColorFunctions bas file

> Displaying A Color Picker Dialog
>
> The modColorFunctions module contains a function named
>   ChooseColorDialog that will display a Windows Color Picker dialog and
>   return the RGB Long color value. If the user cancels the dialog, the
>   result is -1. For example,

```
Dim RGBColor As Long
Dim Default As Long
Default = RGB(255, 0, 255) 'default to purple
RGBColor = ChooseColorDialog(DefaultColor:=Default)
If RGBColor < 0 Then
    Debug.Print "*** USER CANCELLED"
Else
    Debug.Print "Choice: " & Hex(RGBColor)
End If
```

You would need to insert the call to the ChooseColorDialog when you want the user to input the color.